AttributeError: module 'tree' has no attribute 'flatten' while loading Keras model in Flask app (TensorFlow 2)
I'm encountering an AttributeError: module 'tree' has no attribute 'flatten' when trying to load a Keras model in my Flask application. I'm using TensorFlow 2 (version: [12.16.1]), and the code for loading the model looks like this:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

app = Flask(__name__)
model = load_model('mymodel.h5')

error:-
*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ALTARON\Desktop\Project\model\app.py", line 10, in 
model = load_model('mymodel.h5')
File "C:\Users\ALTARON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_api.py", line 183, in load_model
return legacy_h5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath)
File "C:\Users\ALTARON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\legacy_h5_format.py", line 133, in load_model_from_hdf5
model = saving_utils.model_from_config(
File "C:\Users\ALTARON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\saving_utils.py", line 85, in model_from_config
return serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
File "C:\Users\ALTARON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\serialization.py", line 495, in deserialize_keras_object
deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
File "C:\Users\ALTARON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py", line 322, in from_config
model = cls(name=name)
File "C:\Users\ALTARON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\model.py", line 144, in new
return super().new(cls)
File "C:\Users\ALTARON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py", line 217, in new
obj = super().new(cls, *args, *kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ALTARON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py", line 100, in new
flat_arg_values = tree.flatten(kwargs)
AttributeError: module 'tree' has no attribute 'flatten'
model summery:-
**Model: "sequential"

Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 256, 256, 32)      896
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2  (None, 85, 85, 32)        0
D)
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 85, 85, 64)        18496
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPoolin  (None, 28, 28, 64)        0
g2D)
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 128)       73856
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 128)       147584
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPoolin  (None, 9, 9, 128)         0
g2D)
flatten (Flatten)           (None, 10368)             0
dense (Dense)               (None, 200)               2073800
dropout (Dropout)           (None, 200)               0
dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 38)                7638
=================================================================
Total params: 2322270 (8.86 MB)
Trainable params: 2322270 (8.86 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)**

Have you checked this answer ?
